# PostgreSQL prepared statement does not work

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement, database

When I enter the following prepared statement:

```
PREPARE pstmt AS SELECT substring(indhold from $1 for $2) FROM mediefil WHERE id = $3
```

And execute it by entering the following command:

```
EXECUTE pstmt (1, 524288, '{01428c12-6c7c-148b-ca35-9d344dfbf8e8}')
```

I get a strange error:

```
2013-11-25 18:47:37 CET ERROR:  invalid escape string
2013-11-25 18:47:37 CET HINT:  Escape string must be empty or one character.
2013-11-25 18:47:37 CET CONTEXT:  SQL function "substring" statement 1
2013-11-25 18:47:37 CET STATEMENT:  EXECUTE pstmt (1, 524288, '{01428c12-6c7c-148b-ca35-9d344dfbf8e8}')
```

Why does this happen? And how can I make the prepared statement work?

Comment: It looks like the wrong flavor of `substring` gets executed (the one that does pattern matching). What are the version of postgres and the datatype of `indhold`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting the parameters:

```
PREPARE pstmt(int, int, uuid) AS
SELECT substring(indhold from $1 for $2) FROM mediefil WHERE id = $3
```